# How to get the value of a related field with Entity Framework in an Hidden Field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I have a model **Food** that has a navigation property **Vendor**. I will like to view the related food vendor in the view but I keep getting the Id (number) of the Vendor property in the view.

Here's my model:

```
    public class Food
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Food Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int VendorId { get; set; }

        public Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
    }
```

and here's my Vendor model:

```
public class Vendor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Food Vendor")]
        public String FoodVendor { get; set; }

        public String Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's the controller rendering the view I want to display:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var orders = _context.Foods.Include(m => m.Vendor).ToList();
            var viewModel = new NewPlaceOrderViewModel()
            {
                Foods = orders
            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

Here's my ViewModel:

```
public class NewPlaceOrderViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Food> Foods { get; set; }
        public Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
    }
```

I'll be showing the view here but will be skipping a lot of codes for brevity:

```
@model Nominal.ViewModel.NewPlaceOrderViewModel

...

<div class="row el-element-overlay m-b-40">
            @foreach (var food in Model.Foods)
            {
                if (counter != 0 && counter % 4 == 0)
                {
                    @:</div>
                    @:<div class="row el-element-overlay m-b-40">
                }

                <!-- /.usercard -->
                          <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                              <div class="white-box">
                                  <div class="el-card-item">
                                      <div class="el-card-avatar el-overlay-1">
                                          @Html.HiddenFor(m => food.Id, new { id = "food" + counter.ToString() })
                                          <img src="@Url.Content("~/Images/"+ @Path.GetFileName(food.FilePath))" class="lazy" />
                                          <div class="el-overlay">
                                              <ul class="el-info">
                                                  <li><a class="btn default btn-outline image-popup-vertical-fit" href="@Url.Content("~/Images/"+ @Path.GetFileName(food.FilePath))"><i class="icon-magnifier"></i></a></li>
                                                  <li class="food"><a class="btn default btn-outline" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="icon-check"></i></a></li>
                                              </ul>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="el-card-content">
                                          <h3 class="box-title">@Html.DisplayFor(m => food.Name)</h3> <small>₦ @Html.DisplayFor(m => food.Price)</small>
                                          @Html.HiddenFor(m => food.Vendor.FoodVendor, new { id = "foodVendor" + counter.ToString() })
                                          <br />
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                <!-- /.usercard-->

                counter++;
            }
        </div>
```

On this line `@Html.HiddenFor(m => food.Vendor.FoodVendor, new { id = "foodVendor" + counter.ToString() })` it translates to `<input id="foodVendor4" name="food.Vendor.FoodVendor" type="hidden" value="Tasty Fried Chicken">`

Each time I try to print the value of **food vendor** to console with:

```
    var foodVendor = $(this).closest(".el-card-item").find("input").val();
    console.log(foodVendor);
```

I keep getting the IDs of the field. I.e Numbers are been printed out. You will notice that the value of the hidden field is a text with the value Tasty Fried Chicken. ***Why can't I get the text field as a text?***

Comment: Where are you executing this line of javascript  ? what is `this` in this context ?

Comment: I'm executing it on a click event. It now works per your answer. I'm grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will generate the HTML markup for 2 hidden input  elements inside each div with CSS class `"el-card-item"`. **The first one is having the value of the food Id** and the second one has the text field (vendor name). So basically the expression `closest(".el-card-item").find("input.vendor")` will give you both of those inputs. But when you call the `val()` method, it will return the value of the **first item** in the array.

I would suggest using a more specific selector. For example, you can add a css class to your hidden element

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => food.Vendor.FoodVendor, for example,
                      new { id = "foodVendor" + counter.ToString(), @class="vendor" })
```

and in your jQuery code, use this css class as the selector.

```
$(".el-card-content").each(function ()
{
    var foodVendor = $(this).closest(".el-card-item").find("input.vendor").val();
    console.log(foodVendor);
})
```

I personally am not a fan of adding CSS classes just for the purpose of jQuery selection. I would consider adding a html5 data attribute to store this value to a relevant div and read that using the `data` method.